# Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' while uploading image

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller

```
<?php

class Avatar extends MX_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->config('avatar');
        $this->load->library('upload');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Prepare data
        $data = array(
            'avatar' => $this->user->getAvatar($this->user->getId()),
            'max_size' => $this->config->item('max_size'),
            'max_width' => $this->config->item('max_width'),
            'max_height' => $this->config->item('max_height'),
            'allowed_types' => $this->config->item('allowed_types'),
        );

        // Load the avatar page
        $content = $this->template->loadPage("avatar.tpl", $data);

        $title = breadcumb(array(
                            "ucp" => lang("ucp"),
                            "ucp/avatar" => lang("change_avatar", "ucp")
                        ));

        // Put it in a content box
        $this->template->box($title, $content, true, "modules/ucp/css/avatar.css");
    }   

    public function upload()
    {
        $this->load->model("avatar_model");

        // Prepare data
        $config = array(
            'max_size' => $this->config->item('max_size'),
            'max_width' => $this->config->item('max_width'),
            'max_height' => $this->config->item('max_height'),
            'allowed_types' => $this->config->item('allowed_types'),
            'encrypt_name' => $this->config->item('encrypt_name'),
            'xss_clean' => $this->config->item('xss_clean')
        );
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
            $data = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        else
        {
            $this->avatar_model->setAvatar(array('avatar' => $this->upload->data('file_name')));
            $data = array('error' => 'Success');
        }

        $title = breadcumb(array(
                            "ucp" => lang("ucp"),
                            "ucp/avatar" => lang("change_avatar", "ucp"),
                            "ucp/avatar/upload" => lang("upload_avatar", "ucp"),
                        ));

        $page = $this->template->loadPage("upload.tpl", $data);

        $this->template->box($title, $page, true);
    }
}
```

and this is the model

```
<?php

class Avatar_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function setAvatar($avatar)
    {
        $this->db->update('account_data', $avatar, array('id' => $this->user->getId()));
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong, the configs are just my preference right?

```
<?php

$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = 512; // KB
$config['max_width'] = 500;
$config['max_height'] = 500;
$config['encrypt_name'] = true;
$config['xss_clean'] = false;
```

this is what i get when i try to upload the image
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 612

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

UPDATE `account_data` SET `avatar` = Array WHERE `id` = '11'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 328

Comment: Somewhere you're passing an array into your class methods when you should be passing a string. Check line 612 of `mysqli_driver.php` to see what's being handled there and follow the chain of calls back up to see where it's come from.

Comment: That's what I got at line 612 ```$valstr[] = $key." = ".$val;```